# Solving math in python without any built in eval functions or external libraries

Tags: python, math

I need to code a program that can get values from this

Comment: You need a parser: `ast.parse`

Comment: How would I implement that? Can you give me an example

Comment: I found the article at http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm very useful to get started with expression parsing. Your case is, in fact, easier to deal with than the one treated in the article, due to the explicit parentheses.

Comment: @user3274535 Please check my answer for the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem, here is a potential solution. No doubt you could make a much more elegant solution using libraries or lambdas etc. as thefourtheye did in their answer, but this seems to work.

I have done a few test cases at the bottom, set the global `verbose` to `True` if you want debug info:

```
# globals
verbose = False # set to True if you want debug info printed
max_iter = 1000 # this stops infinate loops incase the code does not allow for some input

def solve(problem_str):

    def multiply(arg_list):
        x = 1
        for i in arg_list:
            x *= i
        return x

    def find_innermost(x_str):
        a, b, c, i = [0], [0], 0, 0
        while True:
            i += 1
            start = a[-1]+1
            a.append(x_str.find('(', start)) # find next (
            b.append(x_str.find(',', start)) # find next ,
            c = x_str.find(')', start)       # find next )
            if (a[-1] > c) or (a[-1] == -1):
                if (b[-2] > a[-3]) and (b[-2] < a[-2]):
                    return x_str[b[-2]+1:c+1]
                else:
                    return x_str[a[-3]+1:c+1] 
            if i >= max_iter:
                raise Exception("Infinite loop")

    def do_sum(x_str):
        args = [int(x) for x in x_str[x_str.find('(')+1:x_str.find(')')].split(',')]
        task = x_str[:3].lower()
        if task == 'add':
            return sum(args)
        elif task == 'sub':
            return args[0] - sum(args[1:])
        elif task == 'abs':
            return abs(args.pop())
        elif task == 'mul':
            return multiply(args)
        else:
            print x_str + ': Task not recognised, please modify program or input'
            raise Exception("Invalid input")

    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        if verbose: print 'debug: problem_str:', problem_str
        if problem_str.count('(') > 1:
            x_str = find_innermost(problem_str)
        else:
            x_str = problem_str
        if verbose: print '.'*6, 'x_str:\t', x_str
        x = do_sum(x_str)
        if verbose: print '.'*6, 'x:\t', x, '\n'
        problem_str = problem_str.replace(x_str, str(x))
        if problem_str.count('(') == 0:
            return int(problem_str)
        if i >= max_iter:
            raise Exception("Infinite loop")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = 'abs(add(add(9465,38),multiply(add(63303,146),46)))'
    p2 = 'abs(add(multiply(95,multiply(-1,multiply(13,18875))),multiply(-1,add(18293,26))))'
    p3 = 'abs(add(subtract(add(add(151,26875),122),254),subtract(237,multiply(-1,56497))))'
    r1, r2, r3 = solve(p1), solve(p2), solve(p3)
    print 'p1 evaluates to:', r1
    print 'p2 evaluates to:', r2
    print 'p3 evaluates to:', r3
```

Let me know if you have any questions about the code.

Comment: @ChrisProssner

thank you so much for the programming help. This task has really given me a hassle and your help has been very appreciated. I am trying to code a way to get a crawler in python that will go through different url pages and find math equations like the 3 statements to continuously find me more webpages.

Comment: How do the maths equations relate to a web crawler? Do you have an example URL and what you are trying to find within it?

Comment: I wish I could give you a sample url but it locked by permissions.

Just imagine a webpage with only a set of math equations on it. From there I will be using the numbers I find to route me to new pages. From the new pages I will either have to continue to do the math or arrive at a page with a string saying finish.

Comment: Okay, no problem. In case it's any help I have done code for a basic web crawler in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/q1NEdLJ6. Please could you also mark one of the answers as accepted if they have resolved the question for you.

Comment: I have posted an updated version here: https://snipt.net/prosserc/math_solverpy/ with extra comments etc for clarity and updated error handling.

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting question. Actually, in your case, it is very simple. You can parse the entire source string with `ast` module, like this

```
import ast
import operator

functions = {
    "add": operator.add,
    "abs": operator.abs,
    "multiply": operator.mul
}

def recursive_evaluation(current_element):
    if isinstance(current_element, ast.Module):
        return recursive_evaluation(current_element.body[0].value)
    elif isinstance(current_element, ast.Call):
        function = functions[current_element.func.id]
        args = [recursive_evaluation(item) for item in current_element.args]
        return function(*args)
    elif isinstance(current_element, ast.Num):
        return current_element.n
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unknown Element " + str(current_element))

source = "abs(add(add(9465,38),multiply(add(63303,146),46)))"
print recursive_evaluation(ast.parse(source))

source = "add(1, -2)"
print recursive_evaluation(ast.parse(source))

source = "abs(add(1, -2))"
print recursive_evaluation(ast.parse(source))
```

**Output**

```
2928157
-1
1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was a lot of help to the question. I will need to actually do this for a url which will have data like such:


abs(add(add(9465,38),multiply(add(63303,146),46)))
abs(add(multiply(95,multiply(-1,multiply(13,18875))),multiply(-1,add(18293,26))))
abs(add(subtract(add(add(151,26875),122),254),subtract(237,multiply(-1,56497))))

The three numbers then lead to new urls and so on leading me into a crawler that looks until I reach an endpoint (defined in problem)

Comment: @user3274535 Its not very clear what you are asking. Could you please edit your question and update this information clearly?

Comment: @user3274535 Its still not clear. Could you please update with an example?